# Unable to receive token from webapi and get displayed in Angular 6

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I am using an token based authorization using .net as backend and angular 6 in front end and I have successfully able to receive the token from the server, but after authenticate method is called from the UI the token is reached to UI.

I am using an token based authorization using .net as backend and angular 6 in front end and I have successfully able to receive the token from the server, but after authenticate method is called from the UI I get an error; 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of null.

C# webapi code for authenticate method is

```
[a.Route("api/authenticate/")]
        [a.HttpPost]
        public c.Http.HttpResponseMessage Authenticate([FromBody]User usr)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.UserName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.Password))
            {
                var message = new c.Http.HttpResponseMessage(c.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
                message.Content = new c.Http.StringContent("Not Valid Request");
                return message;

            }
            else
            {
                if (auth.ValidateKeys(usr.UserName, usr.Password))
                {
                    //var pass1 = EncryptionLibrary.DecryptText(ClientKeys.Password);
                    var pass = EncryptionLibrary.EncryptText(usr.Password);
                    var clientkeys = auth.GetClientKeysDetailsbyCLientIDandClientSecert(usr.UserName, pass);

                    if (clientkeys == null)
                    {
                        var message = new c.Http.HttpResponseMessage(c.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
                        message.Content = new c.Http.StringContent("Not Valid Request");
                        return message;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (auth.IsTokenAlreadyExists(clientkeys.UserId))
                        {
                            auth.DeleteGenerateToken(clientkeys.UserId);

                         var response=    GenerateandSaveToken(clientkeys);
                            return response;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var response= GenerateandSaveToken(clientkeys);
                            return response;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    var message = new c.Http.HttpResponseMessage(c.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                    message.Content = new c.Http.StringContent("InValid Keys");
                    return new c.Http.HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = c.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable };
                    //return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable };
                }
            }
        }
GenerateandSaveToken method is as follows:
private c.Http.HttpResponseMessage GenerateandSaveToken(User clientkeys)
        {
            var IssuedOn = DateTime.Now;
            var newToken = auth.GenerateToken(clientkeys, IssuedOn);
            TokensManager token = new TokensManager();
            //token.TokenId = 0;
            token.TokenKey = newToken;
            token.UserID = clientkeys.UserId;
            token.IssuedOn = IssuedOn;
            token.ExpiresOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenExpiry"]));
            token.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            var result = auth.InsertToken(token);

            if (result == 1)
            {

                c.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = new c.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
                //response = Content(c.HttpStatusCode.Found, "Authorized");
                response.Headers.Add("Token", newToken);
                response.Headers.Add("TokenExpiry", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenExpiry"]);
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Token,TokenExpiry");
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                var message = new c.Http.HttpResponseMessage(c.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
                message.Content = new c.Http.StringContent("Error in Creating Token");
                return message;
            }
        }
```

In angular code is as follows:
AuthenticationService

```
 export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;
    private baseUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
}
public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}
    login(User) {

        console.log("User values check"+User)
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()

        //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl+'api/authenticate/',User, {headers,responseType: "json"})
              .pipe(map((user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response

                console.log("user values"+user.headers.get('Token'))
                if (user && user.headers.get('Token')) {
                    console.log("Reached tokens!!!")
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

              /*  this.http.put(apiURL, JSON.stringify(json), 
 {observe:'response'}).subscribe((res:Response) => 
  console.log(res));*/

                return user;
            })));
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
}
```

Calling the above login method from LoginComponent as follows:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
response:{}
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    usr:User[];


    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService,

    ) {
        // redirect to home if already logged in
        if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) { 
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        let frm= JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value);
        console.log("printing form values"+this.loginForm.value)
        console.log("frm values"+frm)
        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }
      /*  .subscribe( t => 
            this.CatalogForm.patchValue
            ({Category:t,SubCategory:t,Description:t,ItemName:t,IAP_Number:t}) 

            , err => 
              console.log("Error messgae:",this.errorMessage)

            );*/
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(frm)
            .pipe(map((data:Response)=>data.json()))
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.response = data,
                    console.log('Response'+this.response);
                   //this.loginForm.patchValue({User:data});
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("Reached Login error!!!")
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });

    }

}

alertService as below:

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AlertService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
    private keepAfterNavigationChange = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        // clear alert message on route change
        console.log("inside alert service!!!!")
        router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                console.log("event:"+event)
                if (this.keepAfterNavigationChange) {
                    // only keep for a single location change
                    console.log("inside Navigation Start!!!!")
                    this.keepAfterNavigationChange = false;
                } else {
                    // clear alert
                    console.log("inside Navigation Start else method!!!!")
                    this.subject.next();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    success(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
        this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
        console.log("inside Success Start!!!!")
        this.subject.next({ type: 'success', text: message });
    }

    error(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
        this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
        console.log("Navigation value"+this.keepAfterNavigationChange);
        console.log("inside Navigation error!!!!")
        console.log("message"+message)
        this.subject.next({ type: 'error', text: message });
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Please note I am able to receive token from the server and the token is exposed as well from server side using below code

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "TestHeaderToExpose") { SupportsCredentials = true });
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnableCors();
```

I should be successfully able to receive the token from the server and ui should display an success message as in below html

```
<div *ngIf="message"
 [ngClass]="{ 'alert': message, 'alert-success': message.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': message.type === 'error' }">
 {{message.text}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AuthenticationService's `login` method, use this, you'll have to pass `observe: 'response'` as well to the `HttpOptions` argument, in order to get the complete response. Something like this:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject < User > ;
  public currentUser: Observable < User > ;
  private baseUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject < User > (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  login(User) {

    console.log("User values check" + User)
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });

    return this.http.post < any > (this.baseUrl + 'api/authenticate/', User, {
        headers,
        responseType: "json",
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .pipe(map((user => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response

        console.log("user values" + user.headers.get('Token'))
        if (user && user.headers.get('Token')) {
          console.log("Reached tokens!!!")
          // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        }

        /*  this.http.put(apiURL, JSON.stringify(json), 
 {observe:'response'}).subscribe((res:Response) => 
  console.log(res));*/

        return user;
      })));
  }

  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you pls explain which HttpOptions I need to add Observe:response?

Comment: @Magesh, yes, you'll need to add `observe: 'response'` to the object that you're passing as the third argument to the `this.http.post` method like I've done in the answer.

Comment: when I copied the same code as you suggested I get the below error:
ERROR in login/login.component.ts(70,19): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Op
orFunction<Response, Promise<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '
atorFunction<HttpResponse<any>, Promise<any>>'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'HttpResponse<any>'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'ResponseType' is not assignable to type 'HttpEventType.Response'
        Type '"default"' is not assignable to type 'HttpEventType.Response'.